# Find an item, search multiline text

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, search, crawling, indexed-column

I have a SharePoint list that contains multiple fields. One of which is a multiline "Notes" field that is not included with the default view. When I perform a search on the list, I can search on any column in the list and it will return a result. If I search for a word that only exists in the multiline text (Notes), I don't receive any results.

[image: "Find an item"]
I created a view that contains the column, and re-ran the indexer. I then selected this new view and performed a search using a keyword that only exists in the "Notes" area. Again, I didn't receive any results.

With the new view in place, I was able to use "Search this site" to receive a link to the list. My users desire to search for something, anything within the list to receive all items with that name. This includes data within the "Notes" field.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Supriyo gave me the info I needed. I had to create a managed property that contained the crawled property that I needed.

This is what I did;

1. Add the new multiline column to the list
2. Add data to at least one item in the list (if you don't do this, the crawled property will not get created)
3. Run a full crawl
4. As a Site collection administrator go to "Site Settings --> Search Schema (in the Site Collection Administration section)"
5. Click "New managed property
6. Type a property name (zNotesField, or whatever)
7. Leave "Text" selected
8. Check Searchable, Queryable, and Retrievable
9. Under "Mappings to crawled properties" click "Add a mapping"
10. This is where things can very. The crawled property is different depending upon what you named it. My column was called noted, so I found it under "ows_notes". I created a test column called "findme" and it created a crawled property called "ows_findme". YMMV
11. Select your crawler property and select OK
12. Select OK to your new Managed propery
13. Run a full crawl

My column data was now showing up in searches (both "Search this site" and "Find an item").

Thanks for your help Supriyo!

Comment: glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Multiple Lines of Text' field cannot be indexed as it's an Unsupported Column Type. See here - [Enforcing Uniqueness in Column Values.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee536168%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Indexing the field is separate from search 'crawling' which is needed for Searches (& its results). Make sure the column has a managed property - see : [Automatically created managed properties in SharePoint Server 2013.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj613136%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

After re-indexing, make sure that the results page has the column managed property - [How to display values from custom managed properties in search results.](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/09/11/how-to-display-values-from-custom-managed-properties-in-search-results-option-1.aspx)

Comment: Wow. Microsoft has made this a bit ridiculous. You pointed me in the right direction. I will post my final solution below.

Comment: I cant answer my own question so I will edit the question.

Comment: I wasn't able to edit the managed properties with my access, but that 'Automatically...' page you linked to indicated that Site Columns, including multiple lines of text columns, get managed properties automatically. So I deleted my List Column and recreated it as a Site Column. Works now!

Comment: Regarding "'Multiple Lines of Text' field cannot be indexed as it's an Unsupported Column Type.": it might be true, I don't see however, how it relates to the question. Indexing != Crawling, as you in your next sentence correctly writes. I can only assume, the OP meant the "crawler", when wrote "re-ran the indexer". Otherwise it does not have any sence, at least in my opinion.