# Searchable column content cannot be found in search

Tags: 2013, search, people-search

I have a managed property (multiple lines of text in user profile) that is both queryable and searchable. Problem is that I cannot search for words written in this field in people search. No results are coming up.

The same property is used in the display template for user results. In this display template, the contents of the property is correctly displayed.

I've rechecked Search Schema a million times and the property really is set to be both searchable and queryable.

We tried removing the tick from searchable, run a full crawl. Adding it Again, running a full crawl. No result.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at the answer to this question: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/103239/find-an-item-search-multiline-text

Answer (score 0):

You say you are using the People tab. When you created your Managed Property did you select the button "Advanced Searchable Settings" and choose the `PeopleIdx`? This will put the property in with the other People properties and make them available (after a full User Profile Property crawl).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the entire search index had been corrupted. Why, we don't know. So we set about deleting the search index and run a full crawl on all content Again.

But sadly, no result.

Then we tried something we actually tried earlier (when the search index was corrupt). All the crawled properties that SharePoint had mapped to corresponding managed properties we changed. So the above crawled property (People:MoreTasks) no longer were mapped to managed property (MoreTasks). Instead we mapped the crawled property to the managed property ContentsHidden.

And ta-da! Everything worked.

So a case of a corrupt search index and a weird flaw in SharePoint (that a people property has to be linked to ContentsHidden) solved it!